# Is there any expiration time for Live Tile Push notification on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

Is there any defined expiration time for Live Tile Push notification on Windows Phone 8 ?

Was not able to find an answer in the official documentation yet.